# How can I make responsive JQuery left margin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this page:

[link](http://bagel.dg-site.com/bagel/)

I put a picture to understand better what they want to do.

http://i58.tinypic.com/2vi4cwi.jpg

My margin depends on the width edge element `"#secondary".`

If the element is 260px width when the edge has to have a certain value.

If you resize the window edge is smooth and watch only the shows.

http://i61.tinypic.com/fk4s46.png

**CODE CSS:**

```
#secondary{
    float: left;
    width: 20.4%; 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    background:url(images/BODY-MENU.png);
    height:100vh;
    max-width:260px;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

   var width = jQuery('#secondary').width();

$('.navbar-fixed-top').css('margin-left', width);
});
```

I tried to update the code above `margin-left` depending on how it is necessary to remain always in the same position my element.

Can you tell me please an idea of how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use .resize();

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
   var width = jQuery('#secondary').width();
   $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('margin-left', width+'px'); // use px
});
```

and you can use if statement  like  `if(width < 260){}`

this is what you looking for??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var changemargin = function(){
   var width = jQuery('#secondary').width();
   $('.navbar-fixed-top').css('margin-left', width+'px'); // use px
 }
 // run function here 
 changemargin();
 // run it again on resize
 $(window).on('resize',changemargin);
});
```

Comment: works, thanks but I have a question ... now everything is ok but if you resize the first time I get on the site does not appear well ... how could I do this? can implement a code in document.ready?

Comment: @cristi you make that action as a function and use the function after document ready and on resize .. or just use the same code after document load directly